# ILGeoNames languages support

Tags: ios, objective-c, geocoding, geonames

I'm using `ILGeoNames` as a geocoding services to search for countries, but it seems that it doesn't support multiple languages, what i need is to localise the search result according to the chosen language i.e. arabic,french,turkey etc... is there's a way to do that with `ILGeoNames` ? if not is there's another objective c  geocoding service that do that ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the ILGeoNamesLookup.m you have this function

```
- (void)search:(NSString*)query maxRows:(NSInteger)maxRows startRow:(NSUInteger)startRow language:(NSString*)langCode {
    NSString    *urlString;

    // Sanitize parameters
    if(!langCode) {
        NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
        NSArray *localizations = [bundle preferredLocalizations];
        if([localizations count])
            langCode = [localizations objectAtIndex:0];
        else
            langCode = @"en";
    }
    if(maxRows > 1000)
        maxRows = 1000;

    // Request formatted according to http://www.geonames.org/export/geonames-search.html
    NSString *escQuery = [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:kILGeoNamesSearchURL, escQuery, maxRows, startRow, langCode, userID];
    [self sendRequestWithURLString:urlString];
}
```

If you put the parameter langCode the search will return in the language you have selected. I have tried with "es" and it is working propperly.

Cheers